# Extremum of $x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

In fact, I have the following function:

$$w:[0,2\pi)\to\mathbb{C}, \quad w(\theta)=i(x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta))\quad(1)$$

whit $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

In order to find the extremum, I equal the first derivative to zero:
$$y\cos(\theta)-x\sin(\theta)=0\quad(2)$$
So, isolating $\theta$, I find that the extremum $\theta^*$ satisfies:
$$ \theta^*=\arctan(y/x)\quad(3)$$
However, this isn't correct because the extremum $\theta^*$ lies in the domain of $w$, $[0,2\pi)$, and the range of $\arctan(x/y)$ is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. I mean, if $\theta^*=\arctan(y/x)<0$ for some $x$ and $y$, this violates the fact that $\theta^*\in[0,2\pi)$.

Could you help me figuring out another solution of (2) with the assumptions that $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: How do you define the extremum of an imaginary $w$? Are you extremizing $\Im w$, which in this case is $w/i$?

Comment: Its a dot product $<x,y> <cos , sin >$

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for remarking this. I actually, as you said, extremized the imaginary part of $w$.  It was unnecesary to write it as an imaginary since my main interest is just knowing what is the extremum of $x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it's ambiguous to consider the extremum of complex-valued function.
So I assume that you are seeking the extremum of $x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)$.

Then,

$$
x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta) = D cos(\theta - \alpha)
$$
where $D = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, $\alpha \in [0, 2\pi)$ such that $\cos(\alpha) = x/D$, $\sin(\alpha) = y/D$.

The extremum is $D$ and it is attainted as $\theta = \alpha$.

Comment: You're right. I'm seeking the extremum of $xcos\theta+y\sin\theta$. But, as I arrived, the extremum is at $\theta=\alpha=\arctan(y/x)$, which I think is wrong because $\arctan $ can take any value between $-\pi/2$ and  $\pi/2$, while $\theta$ doesn't.

Comment: @Sama In your post, the solution Eq. (3) to Eq. (2) is not the unique solution as $\arctan$'s image is defined on an interval of length $\pi$. For example, solutions to $x^2 = 2$ are $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $x = -\sqrt{2}$, not just $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The thing is I need an explicit value of the extremum to evaluate other functions at this point, do you think it  would be fine if I give the extremum the value of arctan(y/x)?

Comment: You see, $xcos(\theta)+ycos(\theta)=D\cos(\theta-\alpha)$ was the argument of an exponential which was the integrand of an integral from zero to $2\pi$ and I wanted to make the change of variables $\beta=\theta-\alpha$. So I thought I require an explicit value of $\alpha$ to define my new limits of integration. Nonetheless, I didn't catch that since $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)$ (as you recall), then $-2\pi<\beta<2\pi$, and here is included the fact that both $\alpha$ and $\theta$ belong to $(0,2\pi]$ . Thank you for that.